# apply multiple svn properties to one file using only one command

Tags: svn

I would like to apply two svn properties at the same file using only one command, the props are:

```
svn:mime-type text/plain

svn:eol-style native
```

I've tried `svn propset` , that unfortunately seems to accept only one property as input.

I'm aware I could use a script to do that, but this is such a common task that's hard to think there's no native svn instruction for that.

Answer (score 0):

SVN doesn't have a built-in command to set multiple properties at once.

You can either call `svn ps` twice, or write a short script to do it.